# What is this bar next to each squad I see via commander mode?

Tags: battlefield-4

After a recent update, I now see this bar that fluctuates a lot throughout a match.  What does this signify?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The commander patch notes for update 2.0 was released today, here.](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/forum/threadview/2979150493891514981/)

> UI - New features:
> **- Squad progression bar added to squads.**

*I am assuming this means the squad progression bar for field upgrades.*

Comment: Correct. That way you don't "waste" squad promotions on a squad that is already maxed out.

Answer (score 1):

That bar shows the commander the field upgrades of each squad.  In Battlefield 2 and other previous iterations of the series, the commander is able to keep close tabs on, and control, every squad on the team.

When played correctly, the commander is invaluable to the team's success and squad leaders that coordinate with a good commander are unstoppable.